# IS Oracle 7 DB Files are compatible with later version ? Oracle 9 or 10G?

Tags: oracle, version, backup, dbf, ctl

I have got dbf and ctl file of Oracle 7 and does not have installation media of Oracle 7. Is it possible to restore these dbf and ctl file to later versions [Oracle 9i or 10G] ?

Thank You
Hardik

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. In order to restore a database, you'd need the same Oracle database version running on the same operating system as it was when that Oracle 7 database was up and running.

As it is an *ancient* database (~30 years old), it ran on an *ancient* operating system. If you have a support contract with Oracle, they will probably provide installation files. What about operating system? Today's machines are 64-bit; what was Oracle 7's database server? If it was e.g. one of Digital Alpha servers, you should visit a museum.

Not very optimistic scenario, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Oracle 7.3.4  then Direct upgrade is supported. Upgrade to the new release using the instructions
if you have Oracle 7.3.3 and Lower then Direct upgrade is not supported, you need to upgade to 7.3.4.

[Upgrading a Database to the New Oracle9i Release](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96530/upgrade.htm#1009472)

Answer (score 0):

There are some commercial tools that claim they can read Oracle database file without Oracle software. For example: http://www.oracleodu.com/en/

Oracle Support has also a tool called DUL (Data Unloader) that should be able to read directly data from database files.